# How to use Parse cached query in offline mode?

Tags: ios, caching, parse-platform

I am trying to use a cached user query as explained in Parse documentation:

```
PFQuery *scoresQuery = [PFUser query];
[scoresQuery orderByDescending:@"score"];
[scoresQuery whereKey:@"fbId" containedIn:meAndMyFriends];
scoresQuery.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkElseCache;
```

When network is available the query is cached, and `[scoresQuery hasCachedResult]` equals `YES`

However, if I turn to "flight mode" and restart the app, the query is not found in cache.

Is there a way to make it persistent?

Comment: Ensure you execute the same query with the same filters,limit,skip, sort, etc. See https://www.parse.com/questions/hows-the-pfquery-cache-stored Moreover, ensure you DON'T clear the PFQuery cache with `[PFQuery clearAllCachedResults]` or that query with `[self.myQuery clearCachedResult]`